# How to generate .so files in systemc using cygwin?

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, eclipse

I'm porting a build environment from Linux to Windows and planning to use Eclipse with Cygwin to build the code.  The code requires systemc version 2.3.3.  However, when building systemc in cygwin, the .so files are not generated.  How can I generate the .so files in this environment, or, is it possible for me to generate them in another environment and copy them over?

I install systemc as follows from the systemc2.3.3 directory:

```
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
../configure --with-unix-layout --enable-pthreads --enable-debug
make
make install
```

Comment: why do you expect a `so` file ?

Comment: @matzeri SystemC generates .so files when compiled in every linux environment I've ever used and they're used in the codebase I use.

Comment: Cygwin is not Linux. Shared lib are usually `dll` as in windows programs.